# React App deployed on Digital ocean gives 404 Error

Tags: reactjs, digital-ocean

I have a validation form on React but on clicking submit m getting "404 Error".
It works perfect on local machine.
//from app.js

```
handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const response = await fetch('/api/emailVerifier', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: this.state,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },

      //body: JSON.stringify({ post: this.state.post }),

    });
    const body = await response.text();
    
    this.setState({ responseToPost: body });
  };
```

//from server.js

```
app.post('/api/emailVerifier', async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  const emailValidator = new EmailValidator();
  const { wellFormed, validDomain, validMailbox } = await emailValidator.verify(req.body.post);
  res.send(

    `response received , welllformed = ${wellFormed}, validDomain = ${validDomain}, validMailbox = ${validMailbox}`,
  );
});
```

i have installed my my validator on server using  npm i add deep-email-validator --save

My Directory on server has

```
asset-manifest.json  index.html   manifest.json      package.json  static
build                logo192.png  node_modules       robots.txt
favicon.ico          logo512.png  package-lock.json  server.js
```

Comment: It's hard to answer your question without knowing more context, ie client & server structure, build and publish scripts etc. However it’s obvious that your web server that implements `/api/emailVerifier` is missing once published to your cloud provider.

Comment: pls chk .. i have update dthe answer

Comment: Might not be exactly what you are looking for, but this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/react-server-side-rendering might help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you access other endpoints in server.js on DigitalOcean? EG: if you create:

```js
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('hello world')
})
```

And make a request to it from your React app does it reach that endpoint?

---

I think you will struggle to run the React app and server from the same location.

If your React app is setup correctly it will try to handle all requests coming to that url.

You could run the express server on a different port to the React app. Then traffic won't get routed to both the React server and your Express server.

Comment: can u elaborate? m unable to understand as m new to react development

Comment: @allabtcoding I have updated the  answer with some more info

Comment: no i tried that..can u guide more in detail as m new to web dev

Comment: app.get('/api/hello', (req, res) => {
  res.send({ express: 'Enter Email Address to' });
});

Comment: @allabtcoding run express on a different port app.listen(4000); .. Then make your requests to app.post(':4000/api/emailVerifier'

Comment: do i need to make changes in  handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const response = await fetch(':1308/api/emailVerifier', {

Comment: yeah - so long as the port matches you should be good